# Do long names for jsonb keys use more storage?

Tags: postgresql, json

Consider the example: Two tables `foo` and `bar`, each with a jsonb column.

- For `foo`, there are a million rows where the value of the jsonb is `[{"a":123}]`.
- For `bar`, there are a million rows where the value of the jsonb is `[{"very_long_key_not_premature_optimization_at_all":123}]`

The json key in `bar` is 46 characters longer than that in `foo`. Would the size of `bar` be 46 million bytes greater than `foo`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Yes key length matters

The bigger the key, the more space to store it. JSONB doesn't do anything special to keys.

## Test Cast

### Sample Data

```
# CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT '{"f":true}'::jsonb FROM generate_series(1,1e6);
SELECT 1000000

# CREATE TABLE bar AS SELECT '{"very_long_key_not_premature_optimization_at_all":true}'::jsonb FROM generate_series(1,1e6);
SELECT 1000000
```

### Table sizes

Now look at the tables

```
# \dt+ foo;
                   List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  |  Owner   | Size  | Description 
--------+------+-------+----------+-------+-------------
 public | foo  | table | ecarroll | 42 MB | 
(1 row)

test=# \dt+ bar;
                   List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  |  Owner   | Size  | Description 
--------+------+-------+----------+-------+-------------
 public | bar  | table | ecarroll | 89 MB | 
(1 row)
```

## Source Code

You can see it in [the source here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/1d25779284fe1ba08ecd57e647292a9deb241376/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb.c#L1408)

```
str = TextDatumGetCString(in_datums[i * 2 + 1]);
len = strlen(str);

v.type = jbvString;

v.val.string.len = len;
```

## ZSON Extension

You may consider checking out [ZSON extension which provides JSONB cross-row dictionary compression](https://github.com/afiskon/zson)

> ZSON is a PostgreSQL extension for transparent JSONB compression. Compression is based on a shared dictionary of strings most frequently used in specific JSONB documents (not only keys, but also values, array elements, etc).
>
> In some cases ZSON can save half of your disk space and give you about 10% more TPS. Memory is saved as well. See docs/benchmark.md. Everything depends on your data and workload though. Don't believe any benchmarks, re-check everything on your data, configuration, hardware, workload and PostgreSQL version.

Comment: In light of this, does there exist any practice of minifying jsonb key names (similar to javascript minifiers)?

Comment: Nah, they're toasted anyway so they're not inline in the table. Who cares about the space? I wouldn't suggest you index on the key. Indexing on the value makes sense sometime, but again key length shouldn't matter. The index would normally link the *value* to the location on disk. I don't make stupid long key names, but I don't also abbreviate them to save a few MB on disk. I created a million rows and saved 27 MB on key length. That's not worth my time to worry about.

Comment: I agree disk space is cheap, but wouldn't it also be wasting memory? And just to clarify: are all jsonb columns toasted (i.e. separately stored on disk), even if they're not >8kb?

Comment: the value itself only has to be 2kb, afaik. the page has to be less than 8kb. (~2 block reads on a modern hd).

Comment: @DavidTan also updated with mention of ZSON.

Comment: Another way to confirm that each additional character takes an additional byte is to use PostgreSQL's size tools without even adding data to a table: `select pg_column_size('{"a": ""}'::jsonb);` = 17, while `select pg_column_size('{"ab": ""}'::jsonb);` = 18, and so on as you keep adding characters to the key.